# Grails gldapo: adding logic on entry create method

Tags: grails, groovy, ldap

is there a way to put some logic on an gldapo entry create method or before/after create events?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several.  Interceptors would work, or just generating your own Controller.  Probably some others that aren't coming to mind right now.

Comment: I want to add logic into the entry event, not in the controller

Comment: You could decorate the gldapo object as per (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Decorator+Pattern), that would probably be the easiest.  Just wrap the functionality you need to intercept (create or update, what have you) and pass through to the underlying object.